# Rails4: What is the correct way to use form_for for submitting a hidden field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, form-for

I am trying to pass a hidden field from a form whose value is derived from a text blob that user can edit on the webpage. (I use bootstrap-editable to let the user edit the blurb by clicking on it)

Here is the actual workflow:

1. User goes on 'Invitations page' where they are are provided with a form to enter friends email and shown a **default text** that will be used in the email
2. If the user want they can click on the text and edit it. This will make a post call via javascript to update_email method in Invitation controller
3. After the text is updated user is redirected **back** so now the user sees the same page with updated text. **This works** and user sees the updated text blurb instead of default [1-3] can happen any number of times
4. When the user submits the form , I expect to get the final version of email that I can save in the db and also trigger an email invitation to the users friend

Problem:
I keep getting **default text** from form parameters. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Here is the form (Its haml instead of html)

```
    #new-form
      = form_for @invitation, :url=> invitations_path(), :html => {:class => 'form-inline', :role => 'form'} do |f|
        .form-group
          = f.text_field :email, :type=> 'email', :placeholder=> 'Invite your friends via email', :class=> 'form-control invitation-email'
          = f.hidden_field :mail_text, :value => @invitation_email
        = f.submit :class => 'btn btn-primary submit-email', :value => 'Send'
```

Here is the invitation controller:

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
  authorize_resource
  before_filter :load_invitations, only: [:new, :index]
  before_filter :new_invitation, only: [:new, :index]
  before_filter :default_email, only: [:index]
  #helper_method :default_email

  def create
    Invitation.create!(email: params[:invitation][:email], invited_by: current_user.id, state: 'sent', mail_text: params[:invitation][:mail_text], url: {referrer_name: current_user.name}.to_param)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def update_email
    @invitation_email = params[:value]
    flash[:updated_invitation_email] = params[:value]
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def invitation_params
    params.require(:invitation).permit!
  end

  def load_invitations
    @invitations ||= current_user.sent_invitations
  end

  def new_invitation
    @invitation  = Invitation.new
  end

  def default_email
    default_text = "default text"
    @invitation_email = flash[:updated_invitation_email].blank?  ?  default_text : flash[:updated_invitation_email]
  end
end
```

Comment: I think your flow is wrong, if user can edit mail text then how come it's hidden in form? If it'll be visible you won't have to send ajax request to update your hidden field.

Comment: Thanks Mandeep. The user can edit the text form like this http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/32/ . This sends the ajax post request to update_email .  Once the user is satisfied editing the email text , then they can enter friends email in the text box below and hit submit. For this submit I pass the 'updated' email text as a hidden parameter. Let me know if the workflow is clear, I will try to describe it better

Comment: Ah i see it's a div and not a text field. Can you post your logs when you submit ajax request to change `@invitation_email`. Are you rendering your form again after you update invitation_email variable?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Rails 4 then you need to permit the `mail_text` parameter:

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
    # ...
    private 
    def invitation_params
        params.require(:invitation).permit(:email, :mail_text) #...
    end
end
```

Depending on your settings rails strong parameters will either raise an error or just silently null un-permitted params.

I have to say that your flow is a bit weird and that it may be better if you actually use a 
more RESTful pattern:

**1. User goes on 'Invitations page' where they are are provided with a form to enter friends email and shown a default text that will be used in the email**

Send a AJAX `POST` request to `/invitations` (InvitationsController#create) it should return a JSON representation of the UNSENT `invitation`, store the returned invitation id on the form.
Note that you may need to setup the validations on your Invitation model so that it allows `:email` and `:mail_text` to be blank on creation

```
class Invitation < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :email, allow_blank: true
    # ...

    # Do full validation only when mail is being sent.
    with_options if: :is_being_sent? do |invitation|
        invitation.validates :email #...
        invitation.validates :mail_text #...
    end

    # ...

    def is_being_sent?
        changed.include?("state") && state == 'sent'
    end
end
```

**2. User edits text**

Send a AJAX `PUT` or `PATCH` request to `/invitations/:id` and update the invitation.

**3. User clicks send**

Send a POST request to `/invitations/:id/send`. Update the `state` attribute and validate. 
If valid send invitation. Display a  message to user.

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
    # ...

    # POST /invitations/:id/send
    def send
        @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])
        # Ensure we have latest values from form and trigger a more stringent validation
        @invitation.update(params.merge({ state: :sent })   

        if @invitation.valid?           
            @mail = Invitation.send!

            if @mail.delivered?
                # display success response  
            else
                # display error
            end
        else # record is invalid
            # redirect to edit
        end
    end
    # ...
end
```